# Gradient from white to transparent instead shows as white to black

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I need how to make a gradient that smoothly transitions from white to transparent for a 2D sprite via a URP shader graph.

It seems like I’m already set up and everything should work, but for some reason the sprite turns from light to black, and not transparent. Why might this happen?

[image: Shader graph nodes]

[image: Scene view with gradient]

Comment: It looks like you're passing your white to black gradient into the output colour pin instead of the alpha pin that controls opacity. May I ask why you're outputting black in the colour channel if you don't want black in the colour channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I did graph incorrectly. I recorded a tutorial for YouTube on how to make a transparent gradient for Unity. Here is the link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKp1sWAEMUg&t=604s

Comment: Please include an outline of the correct steps here, or a screenshot of the working graph, so the answer is still useful even to readers who cannot access the YouTube link.